# what is required to run ajax - does adding jquery to page processes ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new to ajax and running xampp on my localhost
I want to communicate with server by using ajax in my own created page.

I want to know is there anything required to add in head section to use ajax calls ?

In my web page's head section there is no javascript file incluided other than this jquery file

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

is this sufficient to make ajax calls like

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#enter').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'functions.php?id=enter_game',
            //data: {id: 'enter_game'},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
            if(result){
                resultObj = eval (result);
                alert( resultObj );
            }else{
                alert("error");
            }
            }
        });
        });
</script>
```

and in `functions.php` file

```
<?php
include("connection_to_db.php");

function is_sufficient_users()
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$dbprefix."users") or die ( mysql_error() );
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 3 ){
            // sufficient users
            // start the game
            $data = array();
            //$word = start_game();
            $word = 'Apple';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $data['id']['name'] = $row['name'];
                $data['id']['ghost'] = $row['ghost']; 
            }
            $data['word'] = $word;
            $data['game'] = "Game Starts";

            echo json_encode($data);
        }else{
            $data = array();
            switch(mysql_num_rows($result))
            {
                case 0:
                $waiting = 3;
                break;
                case 1:
                $waiting = 2;
                break;
                case 2:
                $waiting = 1;
                break;
                default:
                $waiting = 3;
                break;
            }
            $data['game'] = "Waiting for ".$waiting." more users to start the game" ;
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }

if(isset($_GET['id']) && strtolower($_GET['id']) == "enter_game"){
    is_sufficient_users();
}
?>
```

but there is no response, I tried several changing but no success.
Is there a fault in my code or I am not including the ajax connection file or something ?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: On the client side, including jQuery is all you need to do to make ajax requests. If its not working, there is something wrong with either the way your server is configured or with the php script. See if your server is throwing any errors and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code here

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#enter').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'functions.php?id=enter_game',
            //data: {id: 'enter_game'},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
            if(result){
                resultObj = eval (result);
                alert( resultObj );
            }else{
                alert("error");
            }
            }
        });
        });
</script>
```

you have commented the data that is being sent to the `functions.php` page. And in `functions.php` page you are checking for `$_GET['id']` which is not present.

Other than that there is no problem in your code, considering you have the right db connection and the jQuery file is loaded.

---

If you still have doubt then go with the following code for just testing

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#enter').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'functions.php?id=enter_game',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
               console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

`functions.php`

```
<?php
echo "This is just to see if Ajax is working and it does !";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got the problem and had rectified it, and now on functions.php it shows `{"id":{"name":"fa","ghost":"1"},"word":"Apple","game":"Game Starts"}` but on ajax response I checked it with `alert(result);` and it shows `[object Object]` in alert box. how can I decode this object and can use the values sent from the server in this object.
Any reference to understand will be appreciated sir.

Comment: Please use `console.log` instead of alert. This will be shown in the console of your web browser.  With console you will be able to get the object decodes.

You can get console by going into the developer tools and clicking the console tab.

Comment: And you are using `json` so add a header to your `functions.php` like `header('Content-Type: application/json');`  Now you can get the data from the response like `result.id.name` or `result.word`